# How to start a chrooted directory as a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, chroot

Consider I have a directory, for example `/demoenv`. I would like to start a binary in it as a docker container.

Essentially, it would work like a chroot, but with the numerous extra features (and, with the numerous disadvantages) what a docker container provides.

In this case, it is absolutely not a problem if it can't take part in the very useful docker image/container committing mechanism (I have an alternate solution for that).

Can I somehow do it?

- My first trouble is that in this case, I don't really have an image to start.
- My second problem is that the `-v` volume mount option (parameter of `docker run`) forbids mounting the root partition with the following message:

`docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid bind mount spec "/demoenv:/": Invalid specification: destination can't be '/' in '/demoenv:/'.`

Comment: Finally I've found a workaround: I simply mount all of the root directories with `-v`. But it is very dirty. :-(

Comment: You can of course simply create a docker image from the filesystem, and then run the docker image as a container. Alternately, you could use something like `systemd-nspawn` which gives you many of the features you might expect from Docker in terms of isolation while operating easily with existing directories.

Comment: @larsks 1) I need docker, because I am demoing a docker container 2) making a copy is not okay, because it is big and I need the interaction between the host and the container on the fs level.

Comment: Voting the question to close, instead of answering "it can't be done", I find obviously pathologic. Naming the question as resource recommendation is laughing. Well, the SO is still the s(h)ame.

Comment: Well, it's clearly not about software development, so it is off topic here, but I was trying to be helpful in my comments just the same. I'm sorry you were unhappy with my suggestion.  I thought it met the needs you expressed in the question.

Comment: @larsks I explained, why it is not okay. The created sw is a collection of daemons running in a container. Demoing a docker container in any other as a docker container, well this is not what I wish to do.

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer.  I've tried to be helpful and respectful in this exchange, despite your hostility.  Thank you for posting your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a workaround.

Unfortunately, simply mounting "/" (either with the `VOLUME` command in the Dockerfile, or with giving the `-v` to `docker run`) doesn't work - it can't mount the root directory as a volume.

Furhtermore, `VOLUME` in the Dockerfile doesn't seem to work at all.

The best (or, least worse) solution what can be done: mounting the sub-directories as different volumes. Around so:

```
docker run -d -h demobox --name demobox \
    -v /demobox/bin:/bin \
    -v /demobox/boot:/boot \
    -v /demobox/etc:/etc \
    -v /demobox/home:/home \
    -v /demobox/lib:/lib \
    -v /demobox/opt:/opt\
    -v /demobox/root:/root\
    -v /demobox/sbin:/sbin\
    -v /demobox/srv:/srv\
    -v /demobox/usr:/usr\
    -v /demobox/var:/var \
    demobox
```

Unfortunately, it also needs to have a fake image to run (it is "fake" because all of its relevant `/*` directories will be over-mounted by the docker daemon). You can use anything for that (I used the default image of the distribution).

Additional info: as entrypoint, we can also give `/sbin/init` to the container. In my tries, systemd wasn't able to run in it, but `upstart` could (`apt-get install upstart`). Giving `/sbin/init` as `ENTRYPOINT` to the `Dockerfile`, then calling a `telinit 3` after starting the container, we can essentially run a docker container as a virtual server.